# Problemas de Faulty Service no meu web service

Tags: java, web-service, eclipse, tomcat, axis2

fiz um web service e estava funcionando perfeitamente até esta manha, no período da tarde quando coloquei pra funcionar o webservice através do Eclipse e tentei conectar no endereço do mesmo ocorreu um erro de Faulty Service.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

revirei pra todos os lados e não consegui resolver o problema, não achei nada na internet também.

Utilizando:

> Eclipse neon 3 || Tomcat 6 || Axis 2 - 1.7 || Soap || MySql || xampp 5.6.30
>   || mysqlconector 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvi o problema, apenas troquei o tomcat 6 pelo tomcat 9

fuçando tanto no webservice achei varias coisas de problemas com versão, tentei trocar o tomcat pra uma versão mais recente, funcionou.

espero que isso resolva esse problema, caso alguém a tenha, pois, não existe nada que ajude na internet.

obrigado pela a atenção de todos.